# Como posso alterar a cor de barra de rolagem dentro de um div?

Tags: html, css

Como eu posso fazer para alterar a cor e estilo de uma barra de rolagem dentro de uma div? Eu pesquisei na internet e achei esse exemplo mas não funcionou:

`scrollbar-arrow-color:#000000;
scrollbar-base-color:#000000;
scrollbar-dark-shadow-color:#000000;
scrollbar-face-color:#000000;
scrollbar-highight-color:#000000;
scrollbar-shadow-color:#000000;`

O que eu preciso fazer é isso: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso usa como abaixo alterando os valores.

```
.suadiv{
    scrollbar-face-color: #367CD2;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-track-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Exemplo funcionando = http://jsfiddle.net/hmartiro/Xck2A/1/

Comment: Valeu cara. Muito obrigado